# Argument for @NotNull parameter 'module' of com/intellij/openapi/roots/ModuleRootManager.getInstance must not be null

Tags: pycharm

When I try to run any kind of script, I get this error:

[image: screenshot of error message]

Transcription of error:

> Argument for @NotNull parameter 'module' of com/intellij/openapi/roots/ModuleRootManager.getInstance must not be null

Answer (score 17):

Same in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-222.3345.118, built on July 26, 2022 with plugin Python (222.3345.131).

Solved by:

1. Switch "Python interpreter:" to "Use SDK of module:" in "Run/Debug Configurations"
2. Run and stop script
3. Switch "Python interpreter:" back to "Use specified interpreter:" (I use Virtualenv)
4. Run script

Answer (score 10):

Solved by:

1. Open Edit Configurations....

   [image]
2. Select the desired script
3. Click on the button "-" (Tip "Remove Configuration")

   [image]
4. Close "Edit Configurations"
5. Select the desired script on left panel (Where your project files)
6. Click Right mouse and  select "Run ..."

Answer (score 5):

An answer that worked for me is the following:
https://github.com/raniejade/spek-idea-plugin/issues/30#issuecomment-1451523523

It says:

> It happens when issues occur in .idea directory. Just remove the .idea
> directory under your python project, close the current project. When
> you reopen pycharm, the project directory will re-generate another
> .idea directory, and problem solved.

Comment: BEWARE: deleting your `.idea` folder will cause you to lose your shelved files.
I suggest renaming your `.idea` folder to a different name and then using a diff tool to recover your shelved files.

Comment: @YohaiDevir Thank you for the addition! What are shelved files in this case though?

Comment: Shelving is temporarily storing pending changes you have not committed yet. This is useful, for example, if you need to switch to another task, and you want to set your changes aside to work on them later.
You can read more on shelving [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html)

Comment: Interesting, always thought IntelliJ shelves were using the git stash mechanism behind the scenes.

Comment: Close the project and run in the root of the project "rm -rf .idea/". Now, open the project and work as before.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same with pyCharm 2023.3 . Everything worked fine with 2023.2. Problems appeared after pyCharm update. The fix for me was to edit configuration / modify options, then check "Run with Python console".

[image]

Comment: Edit : RUN configuration worked, but DEBUG did not worked, with the same message. I tried to delete .idea folder, but did not work. I tried the pycharm pro version (trial), with the same problem.

Comment: I finally figured out the bug. My run configurations are saved as xml file in .run folder. With pyCharm 2023.3, I created a fresh run config, with same parameters as old config (2023.2) , and every run fine. After comparing the two generated xml files, it appears that they are pretty different … but with same parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue in a Java project in Intellij with a Python script configured as a run configuration. The module SDK was empty in the run configuration, and nothing could be selected for it because it was a Java project and therefore had no Python SDK's configured. It was set up to `Use specified interpreter`, but regardless it still needed a module SDK for some reason.

Was able to resolve this by closing IntelliJ and manually editing the part of the `.idea/workspace.xml` file where the configuration was missing a module. The `configuration` tag in question had a `<module name="" />`, which was apparently being read as `null` by IntelliJ. Changing it to `<module name="<myModuleName>" />` fixed the issue. It just needed to be not-null since that module's SDK wasn't being used anyway.

Comment: Did the same fix in .idea/workspace.xml and it helped.

For me module name got wrong after project re-import between Pycharm/InteliJ

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ nothing helped me. But by chance I managed to fix it this way:

InteliJ: File-> Project Stucture:

[image]

1. I changed the language level - to SDK default.
2. In the section 2, module, I created a module (I hadn't anything there before):
   [image]
3. Then in Run Configuration I add this module:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just open Edit Configuration and click apply and click run

Answer (score 0):

Only you need to do is select the correct python interpreter of you project in specific field. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7QU7.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using the interpreter selection from the edit configuration.

1. Go to edit configuration
2. Select SDK of module
   [image]
3. You click apply and OK
4. Run the script
5. The edit configuration window will appear and here you will select the "Use Specified interpreter" where you will then select the proper interpreter

[image: ![enter image description here]

6. Then click run. From here you can then run and debug.

I hope this helps!